# OData model does not retrieve data from the server

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to get data from the server:

```
        $this.oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://myserver.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/zumu_contact_person_srv",{
            user: 'TEST',
            password: '12345678',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Accept-Language": "ru-RU",
                "DataServiceVersion": "2.0",
                "MaxDataServiceVersion": "2.0",
                "X-CSRF-Token": "Fetch"
            }
        });

        $this.getView().setModel($this.oModel, "ContactPerson");

        console.log($this.oModel);
```

In view I have table:

```
<Table id="Listing" class="tableList" mode="MultiSelect" items="{path: 'ContactPerson>/contactsList'}">
                <columns>
                    <Column id="vendorNum" minScreenWidth="Tablet" >
                        <Text text="{i18n>vendorNum}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column id="recipientType" minScreenWidth="Tablet" >
                        <Text text="{i18n>recipientType}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column id="supplierName" minScreenWidth="Tablet" >
                        <Text text="{i18n>supplierName}"/>
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem>
                        <cells>
                            <Input value="{ContactPerson>Parnr}" editable="false" />
                        </cells>
                        <cells>
                            <Input value="{ContactPerson>Ebonu}" editable="false" />
                        </cells>
                        <cells>
                            <Input value="{ContactPerson>NameFirst}" editable="false" />
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
```

Why data not come with the server? Object `$this.oModel.oData` - is empty. What could be the problem? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you check if a request is made and if so what result is returned?

Comment: @hirse, He sends three requests:  `/zumu_contact_person_srv/$metadata`, `/zumu_contact_person_srv/`, `/zumu_contact_person_srv/$batch`. $metadata - 200 ok, zumu_contact_person_srv - 20 ok (request with header `x-csrf-token:Fetch`), $batch - 403 Forbidden. Him say: `CSRF token validation failed`. I do not understand why?

Comment: Apparently you are not logged in with the correct user or your user doesn't have enough privileges.

Comment: @hirse, I do not think so. Because user was created in system  specifically for this test case. Also, requests `/$metadata` and  `zumu_contact_person_srv/` - is triggered normally. After them, client does request `/$batch` and the server returns an error: `403 Forbidden, CSRF token validation failed`

Comment: Sanu, Hirse is right. If it is not an authentication issue, it may have to do with other circumstances such as tokens, validity, authorisation etc. Anyhow, 403 means that the server just refuses to give you data, and that's why your model remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

1) The error you are getting indicates that the issue is with your userID and Password. Just pass this request from DHC in your google chrome apps with your headers and you should be getting the same error from the server which means there is an issue with the userId and Password.

2) Since this is only a get request you don't need the CSRF Token validation. hence remove the line,
                "X-CSRF-Token": "Fetch"
from your headers.

"X-CSRF-Token": "Fetch"  should be used to get the CSRF token from  your server in and that token that you received from the server should be passed back to the server in POST or PUT request's.

Try the above two and it should work.